# When to use Firestore vs Pub/Sub

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-pubsub

Can you elaborate on the differences between Pub/Sub and Firestore and provide some scenarios or use cases on which one to choose?

I'm not sure which one to use for building an app for a food delivery service that services real-time updates reflected as soon as they are added or changed to the database, ensuring that customers and drivers are aware of when food is ready for pickup and when food is in transit to their end destination such as UberEats.

Comment: Cloud Firestore would be your best bet of those two solutions. Codelabs may have some examples that line up with your use case https://firebase.google.com/codelabs/firestore-web#0

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The difference is quite simple:

- Firestore (RealtimeDB) is for backend to frontend (customers/users) communication and realtime updates
- Pubsub is a backend to backend message bus for async processing.

In your use case, you won't use PubSub to send notification to your users! Use realtimeDB to perform these updates.

Comment: Thanks for your response!

Answer (score -1):

Pub/Sub is like a notification system wherein you receive updates when something is added, changed or removed.

Firestore, on the other hand, is a NoSQL database for mobile (Android, iOS) and other web apps that can be directly access via native SDK. It can support many data types, from simple strings to complex objects. It also supports whatever data structure that works best for your app.

It is best to use Firestore for your app as it provides realtime updates.

You can check for the detailed documentation of [Pub/Sub](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/overview) and [Firestore](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore#key_capabilities).

For Firestore, you can either use either [mobile/web client library](https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/quickstart-mobile-web) or [server client library](https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/quickstart-servers).

Here's the link for [Firestore](https://cloud.google.com/firestore), containing its benefits and key features.